# Proving that any multiples of integers of the form 4k+1 are the same form

Tags: number-theory

My teacher today gave a proof that integers of the form 4k+1 are always of the same form ( 4k+1), while he did it with congruences and modular arithmetic , I asked if we could prove by induction.
Is there an inductive proof ? And is it the same as inducting on n for (4k+1)^n ?

Please help cyber math geniuses !

Comment: Please proof-read before posting. Your question in it's current form makes no sense

Comment: You can prove it directly!  $(4k+1)(4m+1)=16km+4k+4m+1=4(4km+k+m)+1$.  And, yes, you can then use induction to get it for $n\in \mathbb N$.

Comment: Note:  I took the last bit to mean "the product of $n$ integers of the form $4k+1$ is also of that form."  That is not what you wrote, so if I got your meaning right you ought to edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Integers of the form $4k+1$ are always of the form $4k+1$, that is a tautology.

Comment: Do you want induction on the number of integers that are multiplied or on the size of the integers that are multiplied?  The direct proof that lulu gave is quite simple and covers products of two integers.  Then you can induct on the number to say the product of three is the product of two multiplied by one.  Since the product of two is of that form, you reduce to the case of product of two.  You could do a proof by induction for what lulu showed directly, but you have to induct twice, once for $k$ and once for $m$.  It will be a bunch of work.

Comment: Thank u Ross , yes I meant if u express the integer as n terms ..or (4k+1) ^n and induct on n , not k . Is this legit ?

Comment: As in (4k+1)^(n+1) assuming true for (4k+1)^n. Then it is (4k+1)^n which is by hypothesis of the form (4 q+1)(4k+1) = 16kq + 4q + 4k + 1 = 4[ 4kq+q+k]+1, and that should do it shouldn't it ?